# How to avoid automatic use of jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, styles

Suppose I have two pages:
- page 1 uses jquery mobile and has a link to page 2
- page 2 does not use jquery mobile

Why if I access page 2 through page 1 it appears with the style of jqm, whilst if I access it directly it has a neutral style? 
How can I avoid to have jquery mobile in each page accessed through the first one? I want it just in those pages in which I explicitly defined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on how jQuery Mobile handles links, specifically the "Linking without Ajax" section:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

It says you add a `data-ajax="false"` attribute to a link or parent container to load a link outside the current jQuery Mobile page.

e.g.:

```
<a href="index.html" data-ajax="false">link to a page</a>
```

There are examples at the bottom of that page too.